# Confluent.Kafka - sasl.mechanism set to PLAIN but security.protocol is not configured for SASL

Tags: c#, .net, docker, apache-kafka

I'm using Confluent.Kafka and I'm getting the following error:

> Configuration property `sasl.mechanism` set to `PLAIN` but `security.protocol` is not configured for SASL: recommend setting `security.protocol` to SASL_SSL or SASL_PLAINTEX
> T

How do I fix it? For more convenience, the project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Hulkstance/kafka-dashboard).

### appsettings.json

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "Kafka": {
    "ConsumerSettings": {
      "BootstrapServers": "localhost:22181",
      "GroupId": "kafka-dashboard",
      "SaslMechanism": "Plain",
      "SecurityProtocol": "Plaintext"
    },
    "Topics": ["xd"]
  }
}
```

### docker-compose.yaml

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  zookeeper-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper-1
    ports:
      - "12181:12181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 1
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 12181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:12888:13888;zookeeper-2:22888:23888;zookeeper-3:32888:33888

  zookeeper-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper-2
    ports:
      - "22181:22181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 22181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:12888:13888;zookeeper-2:22888:23888;zookeeper-3:32888:33888

  zookeeper-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    hostname: zookeeper-3
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVER_ID: 3
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ZOOKEEPER_INIT_LIMIT: 5
      ZOOKEEPER_SYNC_LIMIT: 2
      ZOOKEEPER_SERVERS: zookeeper-1:12888:13888;zookeeper-2:22888:23888;zookeeper-3:32888:33888

  kafka-1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-1
    ports:
      - "19092:19092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:12181,zookeeper-2:22181,zookeeper-3:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-1:19092
 
  kafka-2:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-2
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 2
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:12181,zookeeper-2:22181,zookeeper-3:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-2:29092
 
  kafka-3:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    hostname: kafka-3
    ports:
      - "39092:39092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper-1
      - zookeeper-2
      - zookeeper-3
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 3
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper-1:12181,zookeeper-2:22181,zookeeper-3:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-3:39092
```

### Old docker-compose.yaml file

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  zoo:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOO_MY_ID: 1
      ZOO_PORT: 2181
      ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.3.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://${DOCKER_HOST_IP:-127.0.0.1}:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'
      - '15672:15672'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you access to Kafka without a login and password, then simply do not fill in this setting.

```
"SecurityProtocol": "",
"SaslMechanism": "",
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I left them empty, the following occurred`Disconnected while requesting ApiVersion: might be caused by incorrect security.protocol configuration (connecting to a SSL l
istener?) or broker version is < 0.10 (see api.version.request) (after 5ms in state APIVERSION_QUERY)`